# Extensible ad hoc polymorphism? (C++11)

Tags: templates, c++11, polymorphism, overloading

I need to implement a generic algorithm that can operate on a matrix regardless of its representation. It could be a C-style 2D array, a vector of vectors or an arbitrary user class (which does not necessarily provide a subscript operator). 
An obvious solution could look like this:

```
template<typename M>
void func(M& mat, int cols, int rows)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
      for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
         doSomething(elem(mat, i, j));
}
```

...where the user would have to provide an overload of 'elem' that operates on his matrix type. The problem with this approach is that this overload would need to be declared before 'func' for the code to compile, and not just before the template instantiation. Is there a way around this problem that does not involve an ugly function signature or forcing the user to write a wrapper class and other boilerplate code?

Comment: I don't think that "this overload would need to be declared before 'func' for the code to compile": the code will be generated by the compiler only at the first time you instantiate the template. It's perfectly legal to invoke elem() in the template function definition. It's important only that elem(T&, int, int) be defined before you use func<T>() for the 1st time.

Comment: That's not what my compiler (GCC 4.7) says, unfortunately... 

"[Error] 'at' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
[Note] 'float& at(float (*)[3], int, int)' declared here, later in the translation unit"

Comment: @user3026691: In that case, you're using `func` with a `float(*)[3]`.  As he says, `elem` must be defined before `func` is _used_.  It can be defined either before or after `func` is _defined_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried it and found a possible solution after my first comment. So Just including the declaration into the generic function, *it works*! See my example code below.

<strike>The point finally seems to be that the *templetized* code doesn't get the declaration of `elem()` done in the *non-templetized* code.</strike>

It's after the definition of the template, but before of its first instantiation, so, to my knowledge/understanding, it should be enough.... but my complier (gcc 4.8.2) complains as well. I'm sure to have used this feature many times with templetized methods and classes.

It seems really strange to me and possibly a bug (@Potatoswatter: can you give a reference to the bug - see if this match?).

EDITED: Finally understood. Still studying [C++11 Stroustrup's](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html)! It works as intended in the standard. I give here some pointers - excerpts.

The first important idea is suggested in 23.3.2 (*Templates, Error detection*): Syntax error are checked in definitions before they are used in the first instance. Sure they are, but though that it was just defined later. But: "a name used in a template definition must either be in  scope or in some reasonably obvious way depend on a template parameter". This is clear enough already now, but most important is the rationale behind this idea.

It's explained in great detail in 26.3 (*Instantiation [of templates!], Name Binding*): "Define template functions to minimize dependencies on nonlocal information. The reason is that a template will be used to generate functions and classes based on unknown types and in unknown contexts. Every subtle context dependency is likely to surface as a problem for somebody...".

After reading it - I'm still asking myself why I haven't thought to such an important difference, with respect to the controlled environment present within a generic class!!

Explanation go on (pages 745-758!) and the mechanism for the resolution is explained especially in 26.3.2 (*Point-of-definition Binding*) and 26.3.3 (*Point-of-instantation Binding*):

"When the compiler sees a template definition, it determines which names are dependent (26.3.1). If a name is dependent, looking for its declaration is postponed until instantiation time (26.3.3)."

"Names that do not depend on a template argument **are treated like names that are not in templates; they must be in scope (6.3.4) at the point of definition**".

That's stoned. `elem()` must be declared before it's used in the template definition - it is treated like names that are not in templates.

I agree with @Potatoswatter and others. This is probably the less elegant solution, since it restricts to the use of an external function, no functors, no lambdas.

On the other side, it addresses the problem (thought it was a workaround initially... no, it's just how it's intended to work!) of the OP.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename M, typename R>
void func(M mat, int cols, int rows)
{
  // with this declaration it works.
  R &elem(M, int, int);

  for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) {
      elem(mat, i, j) += 1; // +=1 is just your "doSomething()"
    }
  }
}

template<typename M, typename R>
void show(M mat, int cols, int rows)
{
  R &elem(M, int, int);
  for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) {
      if (j>0) cout << ", ";
      cout << elem(mat, i, j);
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

float &elem(float *m, int i, int j) {
  return m[i*3+j];
}

float &elem(float m[3][3], int i, int j) {
  return m[i][j];
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  float mat1d[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  float mat2d[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  func<float*, float>(mat1d, 3, 3);
  show<float*, float>(mat1d, 3, 3);

  func<float(*)[3], float>(mat2d, 3, 3);
  show<float(*)[3], float>(mat2d, 3, 3);
}
```

Trying to use references as in your question I've got slightly crazy before understanding that mixing them with statically declared sizes, let things much more *stuck*. I include it here because I have lost quite some time trying to get around this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename M, typename R>
void func(M &mat, int cols, int rows)
{
  R &elem(M&, int, int);
  for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) {
      elem(mat, i, j) += 1; // +=1 is just your "something"
    }
  }
}

template<typename M, typename R>
void show(M &mat, int cols, int rows)
{
  R &elem(M&, int, int);
  for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) {
      if (j>0) cout << ", ";
      cout << elem(mat, i, j);
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

float &elem(float (&m)[9], int i, int j) {
  return m[i*3+j];
}

float &elem(float (&m)[3][3], int i, int j) {
  return m[i][j];
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  float mat1d[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  float mat2d[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  func<float[9], float>(mat1d, 3, 3);
  show<float[9], float>(mat1d, 3, 3);

  func<float[3][3], float>(mat2d, 3, 3);
  show<float[3][3], float>(mat2d, 3, 3);
}
```

NOTE: in this way `elem()` is a function, included at link time. I think that's not what you want, but then you can get around it making a functor of all the stuff.

Comment: This does the trick! However, the compiler can't deduce the type of R, so I had to switch M and R places to let it at least deduce the matrix type. Thank you! =)

Comment: The potential issue with this solution is that `elem` cannot be a template, but must be a set of non-overloaded functions with the exact signature `R &elem(M&, int, int)`. Likely the reason `elem` wasn't being found was that ADL wasn't working, for example if `M` is `int [3][3]`. Non-ADL overloads do need to be declared before the template, and will be ignored otherwise.

Comment: @Potatoswatter What do you mean by non-overloaded? Isn't the elem function in the example above overloaded? As for the other limitations, they seem reasonable to me, since we face the same limitations when implementing the virtual functions of an interface. Do you think it would be significantly better design to just pass elem as a parameter, as per bolov's suggestion?

Comment: @user3026691 I can't think of what I'd mean by that, looks like a brain fart or typo. Sorry. Templates and conversions are disallowed. Virtual functions do allow conversions. I still think my solution, which is pretty much the first thing you tried, is the most reasonable design. I didn't realize you had defined `elem` to work with C-style array types in addition to classes, but I don't see why you can't declare that particular overload before `func`.

Comment: What if the user's matrix is a vector of vectors? A std::array of std::arrays? A custom array of custom arrays? An arbitrary combination of any of the above? =P It may be a little far-fetched in this particular case, but this requirement was implied in my original question. I suppose both solutions have their use cases and I have some reading up to do about ADL!

Comment: @Potatoswatter I have edited my answer with new insight. I don't know whether you get the update from SO, that's why adding this comment. After this new insight, thanks for your question, I think the answer by bolov is the most general/elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is that a subscript operator should be mandatory.

You are ok to force the user to declare a `elem` function, but you don't want to force him to overload a subscript operator. This doesn't make sense to me. Consider the case when he uses an array or a class that already has a subscript operator defined. Why would you force him to define a function that does what the subscript operator already does?

However this is how you do what you want:

```
template<typename M, typename F>
void func(M& mat, int cols, int rows, F elem)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
      for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
         doSomething(elem(mat, i, j));
}
```

This can be called with references to functions, pointer to functions or lambdas.

Call example with lambda:

```
func(mat, 5, 5, []->int (int **m, int i, int j) { return m[i][j];});
```

I haven't test it so I hope there are no syntax errors.

As a middle ground beside that you could have an overload what doesn't receive `elem` as a parameter and uses the subscript operator.

Comment: It will make sense if you consider that there no '[][]' operator that a user class can overload. They would have to implement a subscript operator that returns another object with a subscript operator that returns the value. Besides, the matrix could be a 3rd-party type the interface of which can't be modified. Also, I'm looking to avoid having to pass the elem as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, this is actually done in practice. The best thing to do is to have the 2 overloads: no custom function, use double subscript; and with custom function.

Comment: @bolov: If `mat` is an `int*`, then `[][]` won't work, but `elem` will.

Comment: If one is looking for other examples like `elem()` to see if it's useful, think about `std::begin()`, `std::end()`.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem with this approach is that this overload would need to be declared before 'func' for the code to compile, and not just before the template instantiation.

This sounds like a misunderstanding; it's much stronger than the actual requirement. The overload called by a particular specialization only needs to be declared before the point of instantiation of that specialization, i.e. before whatever non-template call in each translation unit that first leads to your template.

Before the template definition, you only need *some* function named `func`; it doesn't need to remotely match the call or to be useable for any purpose. It's just a placeholder to let the parser know that your template is making a function call there. This would do fine:

```
void elem( struct unused_tag_type ) = delete;
```

as would this:

```
void elem();
```

Comment: GCC 4.7 complains about using a deleted function. Removing the delete  bit, I get an error about using an incomplete type. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong? Could you please provide a minimal example that compiles?

Comment: @user3026691 That's a GCC bug (which I reported), incomplete type is another bug which has been fixed since 4.7. Change it to a reference, pointer, any dummy that compiles, or just plain empty `()`. My intent was not to be specific but to demonstrate how broken the declaration can be. I didn't mean to break your compiler by completely unrelated problems.

Comment: "only needs to be declared before the point of instantiation of that specialization" That's not quite accurate either. It needs to either be declared before the template definition or it needs to be found by argument dependent lookup, which means it must be declared in a namespace associated with the argument type (at any point prior to the point of instantiation).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I understand what you're saying, but I can't get it to compile, whatever I try. The compiler behaves as if the valid 'elem' definition doesn't exist and always tries to use the broken declaration. This is on GCC 4.8.1 now.

Comment: @user3026691 Perhaps ADL isn't working correctly. I need a reproducible example for further diagnosis.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Could you give a look to my answer below please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is my attempt towards a minimal running sample to demonstrate the problem, and a solution. I have only been able to produce the problem when functions and data are defined in different namespaces. I think this is the most general case.

**Problem** ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9de4797bc2587c73)):

```
namespace X { struct A {}; }

namespace Y { // function-style

    template<typename T>
    void f(T x) { h(x); }

    void g() { f(X::A{}); }

    void h(X::A) { cout << "Hello, world!" << endl; }

}
```

**Solution** ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bf21450e6e562b8)):

```
namespace X { struct A {}; }

namespace Y { // functor-style

    template<typename T>
    struct H;

    template <typename T>
    void h(T x) { H<T>()(x); }

    template<typename T>
    void f(T x) { h(x); }

    void g() { f(X::A{}); }

    template<>
    struct H<X::A>
    {
        void operator()(X::A) { cout << "Hello, world!" << endl; }
    };

}
```

In words, use a template struct (function object, `H`) to do the job and a template function (`h`) only as a wrapper. `H` can be specialized whenever you like (but in the same namespace). Its general declaration and the declaration of `h` should appear before the point of instantiation in `g()`.

**Limitation** ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ca2e2be764e1687)): Unfortunately, this does not work if the return type is unknown, that is, if you replace `H` and `h` by the most general forms

```
template<typename... T>
struct H;

template <typename... T>
auto h(T&&... x)
->decltype(H<T...>()(std::forward <T>(x)...))
  { return H<T...>()(std::forward <T>(x)...); }
```

I've tried and it doens't even work with `-std=c++1y` without the training return type. But I hope this is not an issue in your case.

Comment: I think your solution invokes Undefined Behaviour as per [temp.expl.spec]/6. (Haven't you read the "hidden" limerick?)

Comment: @dyp Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think it *does* care *where* you place that specialization. AFAIK, [temp.expl.spec]/6 requires the specialization to be placed "before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place", i.e. before `g`.

Comment: Well, that's interesting to hear because I'm pretty sure I've written tons of code like this, although I'm not sure the instantiation point may be very very later.

Comment: :) yes, there are even several. [temp.point] describes this; for the specialization of `f` referenced in `g`, one should be immediately after the definition of `g`; another one is at the end of the Translation Unit. [Here's an example from the Standard of the ill-formedness of similar things](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8199a517389c053a)

Comment: @dyp In your example, you're (explicitly) specializing a function (`sort`), not a struct.

Comment: There's also an interesting excerpt available at [google books](books.google.de/books?id=yQU-NlmQb_UC&lpg=PA146&ots=EeiI89_BIV&dq=vandevoorde%20two%20phase%20lookup&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: I copied the example from the Standard (or rather, n3485). I don't think the issue is different for function templates and class templates (the diagnostic may differ). The paragraph does not discriminate between the two: "If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation
to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required. [...]"

Comment: ([n3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf‎) is publicly available; there are more recent drafts but they contain C++1y features)